# UserControl navigate in owning window wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

In XAML/WPF I have main window which contains Frame where I intend to put one of the user controls for given view of application.

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Frame Source="Main/MainUserControl.xaml" Name="Main" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I want to navigate this Frame to other source inside MainUserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.View.MainMenu.MainMenuUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
         xmlns:command="clr-namespace:MyApp.Command"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Style="{StaticResource Localizable}"
         DataContext="{Binding MainMenu, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="{lex:Loc About}" FontSize="28" Grid.Row="1" Command="NavigationCommands.GoToPage" CommandParameter="/Menu/AboutUserControl.xaml" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But the navigation button About remains inactive during execution. I verified correctly that /Menu/AboutUserControl.xaml exists.

I'm obviously doing something wrong. How can I navigate owning window's frame from within user control? Preferably via XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using an MVVM framework. (I have added the critical elements here in case you aren't).

Your MainWindow.xaml should use an "ItemsControl" instead of a "Frame". A frame can work, but a better way is to use the ItemsControl like so:

```
<!-- Main Frame -->
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" Name="MainWindowFrameContent">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainWindowFrameContent}" >

        <!-- This controls the height automatically of the user control -->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="1" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

In the constructor of my MainWindow.cs, I set the DataContext of the window to the MainViewModel:

```
using myProject.ViewModel;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel mMainViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize MainViewModel and set data context to the VM
        mMainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        DataContext = mMainViewModel;
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure if this next part HAS TO be an observable collection, but I have implemented it as such and it seems to work well. The only downside is that I need to manually clear the ItemsControl before adding a new UserControl)

My MainViewModel implements the binding called "MainWindowFrameContent". All of my user controls are initialized within the MainViewModel.cs code. I have an additional ViewModel for each UserControl and assign the DataContext of the UserControl to the individual ViewModel before displaying the UserControl to the main window.

My MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }

    // This handles adding framework (UI) elements to the main window frame
    ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> _MainWindowFrameContent = new ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>();
    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> MainWindowFrameContent
    {
        get
        {
            return _MainWindowFrameContent;
        }
        set
        {
            _MainWindowFrameContent = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MainWindowFrameContent");
        }
    }

    // This handles opening a generic user control on the main window
    // The ICommand implementation allows me to bind the command of a button on the main window to displaying a specific page
    public ICommand MainWindowDataEntryView
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(_MainWindowDataEntryView);
        }
    }
    void _MainWindowDataEntryView(object obj)
    {
        DataEntryVM wDataEntryVM = new DataEntryVM();
        DataEntryView wDataEntryView = new DataEntryView();
        wDataEntryView.DataContext = wDataEntryVM;

        MainWindowFrameContent.Clear();
        MainWindowFrameContent.Add(wDataEntryView);
    }
}
```

Then you need to make sure you have an ObservableObject.cs as part of your project:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And you need a DelegateCommand.cs class as part of your project:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _action;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action(parameter);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

#pragma warning disable 67
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add { } remove { } }
#pragma warning restore 67
}
```

So, it's a bit of a lengthy explanation, but once you have the previous items set up, you can add a bunch of buttons to your MainWindow.xaml, bind each button to a command that adds a new UserControl to your ItemsControl. When your UserControl displays, you can add controls as you would like and use them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: First: this creates strong reference from viewmodel to views. From what I understand it is highly undesirable, viewmodel should be abstract and unaware of actual view implementation; Second: this makes viewmodels tighly coupled, as all viewmodels requires to know mainviewmodel

Comment: It does somewhat create a strong reference between the VM and the view. However, what it is doing is simply controlling which view to display within a different view. Alternatively, each user control could be resource as you have done, but then you need some code to determine when or what to display (if you have multiple user controls). From what I see in your code above, I would verify the DataContext on your user control. It is set to "MainMenu" and the DataContext on your main window is "Main". This could be the problem if you are attempting to access "Main" items from the user control